# Viewstub above a viewpager ()

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, layout-inflater, viewstub

I have a viewpager (with actionbar sherlock) containing 4 SherlockFragment, all inside a SherlockFragmentActivity.

Each tab has it's own backStack (i can stack several fragments ON each SherlockFragment)

**What i'm trying to do is** when i select an item in the list, i want to make visible a ViewStub (which is a player)

**My problem is** that the ViewPager Does not redim itself. The player become visible but behind the viewpager.

Here is the **main SherlockFragmentActivity** :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/ActivityDark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".ActivityMain" >

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/main_stubplayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/fragment_allzic_player"
        android:layout="@layout/view_player" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_stubplayer" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the **ViewStub** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/banner_player_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/cell_height"
    android:background="@color/clr_player"
    android:clickable="true" >

    [...the content does not matter the height is fixe]
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how i make is visible :

```
public void showPlayerBanner(String title) {
    if (mViewPlayer == null) {
        ViewStub stub = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.main_stubplayer);
        mViewPlayer = stub.inflate();
    } else {
        mViewPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try LinearLayout vertical instead of RelativeLayout and set the min/max height to the viewstub.

To know more about the layout differences, the article is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html)

Comment: I gave up the idea of using a viewstub. The linearlayout don't allow to resize a view to fill space between two other view with fixe size (but visible / gone). and i don't want to do it programmatically